# How do I stop my timer when I close my game?

Tags: java, android

**Background:**

**I have a background service with a timer. It opens up a new activity when 20 seconds are over.**

Currently, my app is using `componentCallbacks2` to detect when the user has pressed the home screen, or has left the app, and on detection, I stop the timer, so that the activity doesn't get called.

But, for some reason, `componentCallBacks2` does **not** get called when the user just closes out of the app:

[image]

Here you can see the user closing an app. **For some reason, my app doesn't stop its processes when the app is closed.** And, the timer continues to run. **This results in the activity popping up on the users screen after 20 seconds, even though the user isn't in the app.**

How can I detect if the app has been closed so that I can stop the timer? I have read on this topic in many other sources, and those sources just say to use the `onStop` method. **I can't do that, because the `onStop` gets called whenever there is a change in activities**

So, where should I stop the timer?

---

[Image source.](https://sonru.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/article_attachments/200935872/close_app_2.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html):

> An operation running on an IntentService can't be interrupted

Anyway, there is still a solution based on preventing the launch if your app is closed:

**1/ In your app**

Pass your application pid in the "extra" part of the Intent used to launch the background task.

To get you app pid :

```
android.os.Process.myPid();
```

**2/ In the background task process**

When your task is finished (the 20 seconds have passed), check if the app is still runnning before launching the Activity

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> pids = am.getRunningAppProcesses();

for (int i = 0; i < pids.size(); ++i)
    if (pid == pids.get(i).pid) {
        // Launch your activity because your app is still runnning
    }
```

assuming that the variable "pid" is the pid that came in the intent extra data.

Comment: But on stop method is for the activity, not the application...

Comment: Are you using an IntentService ?

Comment: Yes, I am using a service.

Comment: OK, edited my answer

Comment: I don't understand what is going on in the for loop. Can you explain?

Comment: The PID is the process identifier. A unique id of this kind is attributed by the Linux OS for each process. When launched, your app gets one that is shared with all its threads. If your app get killed for any reason, its PID won't be in the list of active processes. In the for loop, we simply search for it. If not found, it means that your app was killed and then we prevent launching the delayed activity.